# Unity functions called inside 'task.IsCompleted' stop program from continuing

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase Realtime Database to store a list of users and their friends for a game. Saving data has given me no problems but retrieving it has been giving me problems for a couple of days now. Whenever I retrieve data and call any Unity function (I've tested a `PlayerPrefs.GetString()` and `Instantiate()`), the program stops, without any error, but also lets me do other things because it's asynchronous (better explained by code below).

I've tried running it through a debugger and using a bunch of print statements to see what the problem is. However, the program doesn't give me any error so it's been impossible to debug it. I've just been guessing blindly.

I've managed to recreate the problem in the simplest way here:

```
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Database;
using Firebase.Unity.Editor;
using UnityEngine;

public class FirebaseData : MonoBehaviour {

    private void Awake() {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("test", "hello");

        FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("HERE IS THE URL TO MY PROJECT");

        TestRetrieve();
    }

    public void TestRetrieve() {   
        FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("users/").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
            if (task.IsFaulted) {
                // Handle the error...
            } else if (task.IsCompleted) {
                DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;

                print("here");
                PlayerPrefs.GetString("test");
                print("there");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You would expect the program to print "here" and then print "there". However, only "here" gets printed and then whatever code follows the "`PlayerPrefs.GetString("test);`" line will not ever be run. There is no errors given.

This is literally the only script in the project, just attached to an empty `GameObject`.

The weird part is that the print functions and most other ones not related to Unity but just pure c#, seem to be working. It's only the Unity functions which are giving me trouble.

Comment: I don't know much about Unity but is it possible that the problem is around that code being executed in another thread? Maybe some Unity references must be executed in the UI thread? I don't know, just throwing some thoughts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use async event handlers to allow for a better syntax flow.

```
public class FirebaseData : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start() {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("test", "hello");    
        FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("HERE IS THE URL TO MY PROJECT");    
        TestRetrieve();
    }

    public void TestRetrieve() {   
        retrieve += onRetrieve;
        retrieve(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    event EventHandler retrieve = delegate { };

    private async void onRetrieve(object sender, EventArgs args) {
        retrieve -= onRetrieve;
        try {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("users/").GetValueAsync();
            print("here");
            PlayerPrefs.GetString("test");
            print("there");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
             // Handle the error here...
        }
    }
}
```

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! Will using the 'await' keyword force the call to 'GetValueAsync()' to essentially be synchronous since it forces the call to wait until it finishes? If so, does that matter? Will it impact the speed?

Comment: @matematika If you mean if it will cause blocking, NO. it is happening on a separate thread when awaiting and it will return to the current thread when done.